# Serializing ReadItemAsync() response based on a property of the document

Tags: azure-cosmosdb

I need to serialize the response from `ReadItemAsync()` based on a property of the document stored in `Azure Cosmos DB`.

So if `document.type = "dog"`, I need to serialize as `ReadItemAsync<Dog>()` and so on.

I don't know the type before retrieving it.

What's a good solution for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could deserialize it to a `JObject` and read the type property before mapping it to a specific class.

```cs
var response = await container.ReadItemAsync<JObject>("myId", new("myPk"));

if (response.Resource.Value<string>("type") == "dog")
{
    var dog = response.Resource.ToObject<Dog>();
}
```